# Infinity vs Mending

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a bow enchanted with Power V, Flame, Punch II, and Unbreaking III. I have two books, one with Mending and the other with Infinity. It seems like it is good to have Infinity, given that you only need to use one arrow, but Mending renders the bow unbreakable (by using it over and over again). Which one is better?

Comment: Personally, I go for infinity. Inventory space is a precious resource, refilling the arrows is a bother, and with unbreaking III, I have yet to get a bow break before I lose it to lava, void, explosion, or other accidents.

Comment: @SF. So how would I repair this bow?

Comment: Use anvil and unenchanted bow for as long as it allows, then replace with a new one... providing it lasts that long. Unless you're an avid, experienced player of the Hardcore mode, most bows will get lost to 'natural causes' long before they need to be replaced.

Comment: Let's add an Unbreaking III bow has over 1500 uses. That's over 23 stacks, almost a chest of arrows.  And with Power V and Flame most shots are 1-shot kills,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your situation. If you have enough arrows (e.g. skeleton or villager farm) and inventory space, you can probably go for mending. Otherwise, you may have to fix your bow until it is too expensive and then make a new one, but a bow combined with unbreaking 3 will most likely have enough durability in case you don't use it too much.